# F-Keys are Alternate by default on a Gateway Toshiba Laptop 

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I just bought [this laptop](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Toshiba+-+Satellite+Laptop+/+Intel®+Core™+i3+Processor+/+15.6%22+Display+/+4GB+Memory+/+500GB+Hard+Drive+-+Black/1974715.p?id=1218303652901&skuId=1974715&st=toshiba%20satellite%20laptop%20intel%20i3%20processor%204gb%20500gb%20black&cp=1&lp=2).

It's a Gateway branded Toshiba laptop. The F-keys (<kbd>F1</kbd> ... <kbd>F12</kbd>) all have default and alternate actions. Default actions are when you press the key, alternate actions are achieved by holding  the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and pressing them.

The problem I have is that the "unusual" actions (like Gateway backup) are the defaults for the F keys. So when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh, it uses the alternate functionality (try to connect to a projector).

How can I flip the default and alternate functionality, i.e. make <kbd>F5</kbd> a real "F5" and not the special key functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually there is a BIOS/CMOS setting to select the default functionality of those keys.

Check there for an option which chooses F-keys or functions, something like that.

Really that's the only place to look, as the Fn-Fx keystrokes are interpreted by the hardware long before the OS sees the input.  On some older machines, there was a control panel applet which twiddled bits in the cmos settings to change things.  Icky.

Comment: Genius. It was indeed in the CMOS.